# how to deploy vite ssr in the aws ec2 server?

Tags: vite, server-side-rendering

my vite ssr is running good in my localhost by http://localhost:5173 then i am creating a build version by npm run build. it is creating two folder inside dist. one is client and one is server. then i am uploading it to my aws ec2 server in a folder named frontendssr. now i want to server my ssr through mysite.com/v2. Problem is what will be nginx config and what will be the pm2 command? I am confused because in backend server we have server.js to run throung pm2. can anyone suggest me how can  mysite.com/v2 will server http://localhost:5173